# what is GREEDYDATA in elasticsearch

Tags: wildcards, pattern-matching, elasticsearch, logstash

reading the conf files of `logstash` i found in filter conf

```
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "Put\s*command\s*:\s+%{GREEDYDATA:command}" }
    }
```

How does this filter work , i tried to search for `GREEDYDATA` but i couldn't understand

Answer (score 3):

GREEDYDATA means .*     In grok patterns, which are a form of regular expression, a wildcard can be considered “greedy” when they expand to the most characters that it can based on the limits placed around it. So “foo.*baz” as a search on “foo bar baz foo bar baz” will return the entire string and not just the first hit. Your example will put everything matched by GREEDYDATA (.*) into the “command” variable.